# XML schema can have multiple choices in a single complexType?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

Is it possible to do something like this in an XML schema?

```
<xsd:complexType name="ItemsType">
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element ref="shirt"/>
    <xsd:element ref="hat"/>
    <xsd:element ref="umbrella"/>
  </xsd:choice>
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
    <xsd:element ref="apple"/>
    <xsd:element ref="banana"/>
    <xsd:element ref="strawberry"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

this is apparently invalid though. What I would like is for it to be possible to have 0 or more of the first choice.. E.g. there could be a shirt element and a hat element, or perhaps no clothes elements at all (since minOccurs="0"), followed by at least 1 fruit elements (I want to make it so there has to be at least one, since minOccurs="1").

is there a way to do it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks valid to me; did you simplify the example and hide a problem by mistake? This would become invalid if the second choice contained an element that also appears in the first choice...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<xsd:complexType>` expects to have only one child element. Wrap your two choices inside a single `<xsd:sequence>`.

Example

```
<xsd:complexType name="ItemsType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      ... clothes ...
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
      ... fruits ...
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: @jasso But that requires that the clothes choice be specified before the fruit choice in the xml, right? Is there a way to not require that ordering?

Comment: @DavidDoria First solution that comes to my mind is to create a duplicate of the sequence that only has the order of the contents swapped, then wrap those two sequences inside a choice element. Generally in such case you should probably use groups to simplify the code. Also in this case you should be careful not to make the structure nondeterministic, since the clothes-choice is optional. This can be solved by making the clothes-choice mandatory if they appear first and optional in the swapped sequence where fruits appear first.